# How can we embed GoodData platform dashboard onto GoodDataUI

Tags: reactjs, gooddata

On the Official GoodData website some code is given for the integration, but I am unable to understand how to use it.

[Link for the Dashboard integration code](https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/dashboard_component.html)

In my case QuantitativeAnalysis is the dashboard I created in GoodData platform and now I want to view that dashboard in GoodData UI.

[Picture of my code for embedding dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC6gS.png)

Comment: Can you please share the whole file including imports? What is the error the editor is complaining about?

Comment: Hey Dan, I tried modifying the code. It is working just fine.